# Enable drag and drop of a row just if dragging is done on a specific column

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I enabled drag and drop of a row on my grid by adding the following code to configuration parameters:

```
viewConfig: {
        plugins: {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragGroup: 'firstGridDDGroup',
            dropGroup: 'firstGridDDGroup'
        }
    }
```

It works, anyway I'd like for the dragging to happen just if the user does it by dragging an element belonging to the first column.

My idea is to add a "move" column, like this:

```
move| name | surname | age |
<-> | alex | cross   | 24  |
<-> | jim  | reynor  | 35  |
```

If I want to move second row (jim) in the first row I have to position my mouse on the '<->' symbol and then drag, on the contrary if I position my mouse on the, say, "surname" column drag and drop should be disabled.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a `tdCls` to your column that you want to enable the drag on and then hook in the `onBeforeDrag` listener onto the `dragZone` via a config for it.  Then you would test if the event targets parent has your class and then either return `false` to cancel the drag or nothing to allow it to continue.

E.g :-

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'movecol'],
            data: [
                ["Lisa", "<-->"],
                ["Bart", "<-->"],
                ["Homer", "<-->"],
                ["Marge", "<-->"]
            ],
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: 'array'
            }
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: 'simpsonsStore',
            columns: [{
                header: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: true
            }, {
                header: 'Drag',
                dataIndex: 'movecol',
                flex: true,
                tdCls: 'myDraggable'
            }],
            viewConfig: {
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                    dragText: 'Drag and drop to reorganize',
                    dragZone: {
                        onBeforeDrag: function(data, e) {
                            console.log(data, e);
                            draggedCell = Ext.get(e.target.parentNode);
                            if (draggedCell.hasCls('myDraggable')) {
                                console.log('yes i can be dragged');
                            } else {
                                console.log('no I cannot be dragged');
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Working demo here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j0l